# ATM machine - dispense limited amount of notes, not dispensing correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm working on a spring application, ATM machine essentially, basic functionality, trying to withdraw notes from the ATM which should dispense the minimum number of notes per withdrawal. The ATM has a limited amount of notes per denomination also, I'm using a mysql backend for the accounts and teller stuff such as notes total amount of cash etc, created an INoteBucket Interface

```
interface INoteBucket
{
    public int GetDemon();
    public boolean TakeNotes(int qtyofnotes);
    public boolean CheckTakeNote();
}
class NoteBucket implements INoteBucket
{
    private int Denominator;
    private int AmountOfNotes;


public NoteBucket(int denom, int notes){
    this.Denominator = denom;
    this.AmountOfNotes = notes;
}

public boolean CheckTakeNote(){
    if(this.AmountOfNotes > 0)
        return true;
        
    return false;
    
}

public int GetDemon(){
    return this.Denominator;
}

public boolean TakeNotes(int qtyofnotes){
    if (this.AmountOfNotes >= qtyofnotes)
    {
        this.AmountOfNotes -= qtyofnotes;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I also have a "dispense" function (maybe a poor name) that's meant to implement the interface (which it does), but when I "withdraw" money, the function seems to let me withdraw over the amount of notes I actually have, i.e, if I have 2 50s, 10 20s, 10 10s and 5 5s stored in the ATM machine and try to withdraw 200 the result is 4 50s were withdrawn from the ATM with the backend value in the database being stored -2 50s, don't know why? looks correct?

```
public String dispense(@RequestBody Teller teller, @PathVariable Double amount) {
    String notes = "";
    ArrayList<INoteBucket> NoteBuckets = new ArrayList<INoteBucket>();
    NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(50,teller.getFifty()));
    NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(20,teller.getTwenty()));
    NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(10,teller.getTen()));
    NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(5,teller.getFive()));

    while(amount > 0)
    {
      for(INoteBucket noteBucket : NoteBuckets)
      {
          if(amount >= noteBucket.GetDemon() && noteBucket.CheckTakeNote())
          {
             //We know that the remaining request amount is greater than the current denominator && we're allowed to take a note
              double remainder = amount % noteBucket.GetDemon();
              if(remainder < amount)
              {
                  notes += "Amount of: " + Integer.toString(noteBucket.GetDemon()) + " : " + Double.toString((amount - remainder) / noteBucket.GetDemon()) + "\n";
                  
                  if(noteBucket.GetDemon() == 50) {
                      int updatefifty = (int) (teller.getFifty() - ((amount - remainder) / noteBucket.GetDemon()));
                      teller.setFifty(updatefifty);
                      tellerService.updateTeller(teller);
                  }
                  
                  if(noteBucket.GetDemon() == 20) {
                      int updatetwenty = (int) (teller.getTwenty() - ((amount - remainder) / noteBucket.GetDemon()));
                      teller.setTwenty(updatetwenty);
                      tellerService.updateTeller(teller);
                  }
                  
                  if(noteBucket.GetDemon() == 10) {
                      int updateten = (int) (teller.getTen() - ((amount - remainder) / noteBucket.GetDemon()));
                      teller.setTen(updateten);
                      tellerService.updateTeller(teller);
                  }
                  
                  if(noteBucket.GetDemon() == 5) {
                      int updatefive = (int) (teller.getFive() - ((amount - remainder) / noteBucket.GetDemon()));
                      teller.setFive(updatefive);
                      tellerService.updateTeller(teller);
                  }
                  
                  amount = remainder;
              }
              
          }
          
      }
        
    }
    return notes;
}
```

Here is a simplified basic java application with the same implementation which has the same issue

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      ArrayList<INoteBucket> NoteBuckets = new ArrayList<INoteBucket>();
      //Add Notes
      NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(50,2));
      NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(20,15));
      NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(10,20));
      NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(5,10));
      
      int RequestAmount = 200;
      
      while(RequestAmount >= 0)
      {
        for(INoteBucket noteBucket : NoteBuckets)
        {
            if(RequestAmount >= noteBucket.GetDemon() && noteBucket.CheckTakeNote())
            {
               //We know that the remaining request amount is greater than the current demoninator && we're allowed to take a note
                int remainder = RequestAmount % noteBucket.GetDemon();
                if(remainder < RequestAmount)
                {
                    System.out.println("Amount of: " + Integer.toString(noteBucket.GetDemon()) + " : " + Integer.toString((RequestAmount - remainder) / noteBucket.GetDemon()));
                    RequestAmount = remainder;
                }
                
            }
            
        }
          
      }
     
    }
}

interface INoteBucket
{
    public int GetDemon();
    public boolean TakeNotes(int qtyofnotes);
    public boolean CheckTakeNote();
}
class NoteBucket implements INoteBucket
{
    private int Denominator;
    private int AmountOfNotes;
   
    public NoteBucket(int denom, int notes){
        this.Denominator = denom;
        this.AmountOfNotes = notes;
    }
    
    public boolean CheckTakeNote(){
        if(this.AmountOfNotes > 0)
            return true;
            
        return false;
        
    }
    
    public int GetDemon(){
        return this.Denominator;
    }
    
    public boolean TakeNotes(int qtyofnotes){
        if (this.AmountOfNotes >= qtyofnotes)
        {
            this.AmountOfNotes -= qtyofnotes;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please give a console log of amount and noteBucket.GetDemon() in foreach. Your code need to refactor because it do too many thing in one function ...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using the basic implementation, should be this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      ArrayList<INoteBucket> NoteBuckets = new ArrayList<INoteBucket>();
      //Add Notes
      NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(50,2));
      NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(20,15));
      NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(10,20));
      NoteBuckets.add(new NoteBucket(5,10));
      int remainder = 0;
      int RequestAmount = 200;

      while(RequestAmount > 0)
      {
        for(INoteBucket noteBucket : NoteBuckets)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while(remainder >= 0 && noteBucket.CheckTakeNote()){
                remainder = RequestAmount - noteBucket.GetDemon();
                noteBucket.TakeNotes(1);
                counter += 1;
                RequestAmount = remainder;
                if(RequestAmount == 0)
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("Note: " + noteBucket.GetDemon() + " Count: " + counter);
            if(RequestAmount == 0)
                    break;
        }
      }
    }
}
          
 
  
interface INoteBucket
{
    public int GetDemon();
    public int GetNotes();
    public boolean TakeNotes(int qtyofnotes);
    public boolean CheckTakeNote();
}
class NoteBucket implements INoteBucket
{
    private int Denominator;
    private int AmountOfNotes;
   
    public NoteBucket(int denom, int notes){
        this.Denominator = denom;
        this.AmountOfNotes = notes;
    }
    
    public boolean CheckTakeNote(){
        if(this.AmountOfNotes > 0)
            return true;
            
        return false;
        
    }
    
    public int GetDemon(){
        return this.Denominator;
    }
    
    public int GetNotes(){
        return this.AmountOfNotes;
    }
    
    public boolean TakeNotes(int qtyofnotes){
        if (this.AmountOfNotes >= qtyofnotes)
        {
            this.AmountOfNotes -= qtyofnotes;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).